# VSCode debugging, passing file as Python module

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-testing, vscode-debugger

I am working on a Django project and I use VSCode for an editor.

More so, I've found the IDE capabilities very useful.  So now I'm trying to debug the tests that have failed before.

In the debugging configuration I have the following:

```
{
  "name"    : "Django: TestServer",
  "type"    : "python",
  "request" : "launch",
  "program" : "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
  "console" : "integratedTerminal",
  "env"     : {"STAGING_SERVER": "staging.my_server.com"},
  "args"   : ["test", ${file}],
  "django"  : true
}
```

On starting the debugger I get a message that says:

```
File does not exist "/home/diego/project/manage.py test 
/home/diego/project/func_tests/test_login.py"
```

When I run that test on my own, I do:

```
.../project$ python manage.py test func_tests.test_login
```

That is, writing the test address as Python modules instead of folders.

I've read the documentation on VSCode about Django debugging and didn't find anything on this.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Python extension for VS Code doesn't have that level of support for Django testing at the moment. You can follow the [Django testing feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/73) to know when something lands.